# Problemas com o padrão OpenSessionInViewer + JPA + Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, tomcat, cdi

Olá, estou usando o Tomcat + JPA + Vraptor 4 e estou utilizando o cdi para injetar o EntityManager da seguinte forma.

EntityManagerFactoryCreator:

```
public class EntityManagerFactoryCreator {
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Produces
    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(){
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
    }

    public void destroy(@Disposes EntityManagerFactory factory){
       if(factory.isOpen()){
           factory.close();
       }
    }
}
```

EntityManagerCreator:

```
public class EntityManagerCreator {
   private EntityManagerFactory factory;

  /**
   *  @depreciated CDI eyes only
   */
    public EntityManagerCreator() {}

    @Inject
    public EntityManagerCreator(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    @Produces @RequestScoped
    public EntityManager getEntityManager(){
       return factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void destroy(@Disposes EntityManager entityManager){
       if(entityManager.isOpen()){
          entityManager.close();
       }
    }
}
```

GenericDAO:

```
public abstract class DAO < T > {
/**
* EntityManager
*/
@
Inject private EntityManager em;

/**
* Faz referência aos DAOS
*/
private Class < T > clazz;

public DAO() {
        clazz = getClazz();
}

@
Transactional
public boolean create(T entity) {
        try {
                em.getTransaction().begin();
                em.persist(entity);
                em.getTransaction().commit();
                return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
        }
}

@
Transactional
public boolean update(T entity) {
        try {
                em.getTransaction().begin();
                em.merge(entity);
                em.getTransaction().commit();
                return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
        }
}

public T getById(Long id) {
        return em.find(clazz, id);
}

@
Transactional
public boolean remove(Long id) {
        try {
                T entity = em.find(clazz, id);
                em.getTransaction().begin();
                em.remove(entity);
                em.getTransaction().commit();
                return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
        }
}

public List < T > list() {
        try {
                return em.createQuery("FROM " + clazz.getName(), clazz).getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
        }
}

@
SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Class < T > getClazz() {

        Class <? > classeDAO = this.getClass();

        while (classeDAO.getSuperclass() != DAO.class) {
                classeDAO = classeDAO.getSuperclass();
        }

        ParameterizedType tipo = (ParameterizedType) classeDAO.getGenericSuperclass();

        Class < T > clazz = null;

        try {
                clazz = (Class < T > ) tipo.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        } catch (ClassCastException exception) {
                throw exception;
        }
        return clazz;
}
}`
```

Quando a classe ServerDAO é instanciada no Controller, a conexão é aberta e fechada normalmente. Porém, se for instanciada em um Job do Quartz por exemplo e tentar fazer uma listagem com o método list(), ocorre o seguinte erro.

> 19:16:01,662 ERROR [TaskLogger ] Task serverTask was failed
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at br.com.serverus.tasks.ServerTask.execute(ServerTask.java:36)
>   at br.com.serverus.tasks.ServerTask$Proxy$$$WeldClientProxy.execute(Unknown Source)
>   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.tasks.jobs.simple.ConcurrentJobWrapper.execute(ConcurrentJobWrapper.java:20)
>   at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
>   at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)

Se eu remover a propriedade @RequestScoped do EntityManagerCreator, a listagem funciona, mas a conexão é mantida aberta.

Se eu disparar um evento do cdi, e utilizar o @Inject ServerDAO as conexão continuam abertas.

Como posso fazer para fechar a conexão, ou usar uma abordagem melhor sem o padrão OpenSessionInView?

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que, se você coloca o Producer do `EntityManager` como `@RequestScoped`, ele só instanciado e injetado em dependências de instancias que têm justamente este mesmo escopo.

E como o Job/Task do seu Quartz provavelmente tem um escopo diferente a Injeção não funciona (por conta de `NullPointer`). Esta é a prova cabal de porquê o `OpenSessionInView` / `OpenEntitymanagerInView` é um **anti**-padrão e é um dos motivos pelo qual deve ser evitado sempre que possível. Tente mudar o escopo (do Producer) para `@Dependent`

Caso isso não funcione, as soluções, mais próximas do estado-da-arte, são usar alguma Extensão-CDI(como o Delta-Spike, p/ex.) que faça a Injeção do `EntityManager` segundo a especificação-JSR; ou então usar o plugin JPA do vRaptor.